# DuplicateSubnetsInSameZone error when creating VPC endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I have three services: db, api, and frontend, that I am trying to deploy onto AWS using terraform.

Each service gets a subnet in each of two AZs, i.e.:

- `private-api-a: eu-west-2a`
- `private-api-b: eu-west-2b`
- `private-db-a: eu-west-2a`
- `private-db-b: eu-west-2b`
- `private-frontend-a: eu-west-2a`
- `private-frontend-b: eu-west-2b`

In order to provide the ECS tasks with access to ECR and Cloudwatch, I have defined the following VPC endpoints:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr_dkr" {
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ecr.dkr"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  private_dns_enabled = true

  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.vpc_endpoints.id]
  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.private-api-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-api-b.id,
    aws_subnet.private-db-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-db-b.id,
    aws_subnet.private-frontend-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-frontend-b.id

  ]

  tags = {
    "Name" = "$ecr-dkr"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ecr_api" {
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ecr.api"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  private_dns_enabled = true

  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.vpc_endpoints.id]
  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.private-api-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-api-b.id,
    aws_subnet.private-db-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-db-b.id,
    aws_subnet.private-frontend-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-frontend-b.id

  ]

  tags = {
    "Name" = "ecr-api"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "cloudwatch_api" {
  vpc_id              = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.logs"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  private_dns_enabled = true

  security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.vpc_endpoints.id]
  subnet_ids = [
    aws_subnet.private-api-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-api-b.id,
    aws_subnet.private-db-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-db-b.id,
    aws_subnet.private-frontend-a.id,
    aws_subnet.private-frontend-b.id

  ]

  tags = {
    "Name" = "cloudwatch-api"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.s3"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Gateway"

  route_table_ids = [
    aws_route_table.private-api.id,
    aws_route_table.private-db.id,
    aws_route_table.private-frontend.id
  ]

  tags = {
    "Name" = "s3"
  }
}
```

This throws an error: `creating EC2 VPC Endpoint (com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ecr.dkr): DuplicateSubnetsInSameZone:...` for each of the endpoints (excepting S3), but it works fine if I only specify the two private subnets for a single service. I understand that this is because api-a and api-b are in different AZs, but since the VPC endpoint does not seem to be tied to an AZ, I do not know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoints are not needed to be created per subnet.  You just need to define a subnet per unique AZ.
From AWS docs: Choose a subnet in your VPC to use the interface endpoint. For each interface endpoint, you can choose only one subnet per Availability Zone.